# Navigation not being generated for spawned Instanced Static Meshes Unless Moved In Editor

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I currently have an actor that procedurally generates Instanced Static Meshes to create a "dungeon" as part of the construction script (calls a custom event in the event graph). If I place the actor in a level, the navigation mesh volume will generate navigation on the Instanced Static Meshes, however, if I spawn the actor into the level it does not. If I spawn the actor at the start of the level and then simulate the level, I can then drag to move the actor, which then results in the navigation being built on the Instanced Static Meshes.

I've tested this with just a simple actor that spawns a single Instanced Static Mesh from the ConstructionScript node and it has the exact same behavior. I have the navigation mesh runtime generation setting set to dynamic.

I've attached an image showing a white box (Static Mesh), a checkered box (an actor that spawns Instanced Static Mesh that has been placed in the level), and the larger area (my actor that is spawned on BeginPlay of the level). The left image is how it appears as soon as the level is loaded, and the right is after I have dragged to move the generation actor in the editor.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

[image: Before and after moving the actor in editor]

Answer (score 0):

These similar issue pains me so much until I finally found something behind it.

It seemed that as long as you call **ClearInstance** (no matter in blueprint or c++), the navigation data of that (hierarchical) instanced static mesh component will just disappear. After that, all newly added instance will also be lacking of navigation data. I guess its an internal bug in the engine... Anyways, my solution is to replace all the use of **ClearInstance** by **RemoveInstance** (loop all instance to remove one by one).

Replace

```cpp
HISM->ClearInstance(); // HISM: hierarchical instanced static mesh component
```

to

```cpp
while (HISM->GetInstanceCount() > 0)
{
    HISM->RemoveInstance(0);
}
```

It should be very insufficient, but at least the issue is solved in my case.

Hope this will work for you~

Comment: Is the reshuffling efficient enough to justify removing at zero? I would default to removing from the end of the list.